# Common Lisp - Print on One Line / Return / Single Line Counter / Formatting

Tags: lisp, format, progress-bar, common-lisp

I'm interested in implementing a "single line" counter / progress bar in Common Lisp. Nothing fancy, just something like:

=>

==>

===>
... etc..

And then have it start over again. Or maybe count the number of nodes I've visited.

But, I want to do this all on one line, and clear the previously printed characters. For example, in Python, it would be something like:

```
for i in range(0,1000):    
    print "\r",i,"   "
```

Which would then count, but keep everything on a single line, while clearing everything printed on that line before any given iteration.

I know in lisp there is `(format t "text" #\return)`, but that doesn't seem to work.

Does anyone know how I might do this? (I've looked around and can't seem to find anything).

Thanks,

Andrew

***EDIT:***

I found the solution. You need to add a directive (the general-purpose "`~A`" worked) for the `#\return` to be processed:

```
(loop for i from 0 to 50000 do
        (format t "~A~A         " #\return i))
```

This will count to 50,000 and you can watch it do it. So, It'll work for any other situation you might want to reuse a single output line.

Comment: @wvxvw: I think he wants to print a return, not a newline.

Comment: @andrewm921 please post your answer, accept it and specify which lisp implementation and platform you're using.

Answer (score 1):

```
 (defun show-progress (len)
  (format t "=")
  (dotimes
      (i len)
    (format t "="))
  (format t ">")
 )
```

After execute this function you should see this output:

```
CL-USER> (show-progress 10)
===========>
NIL
```

Comment: Yea, that would work, but if you wanted have it wrap back around (if, say, you're not actually measuring progress but providing a visual distraction) that wouldn't work as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
(defun progress-bar ()
  (dotimes (i 100)
    (format t "~a>" (make-string i :initial-element #\=))
    (finish-output)
    (sleep 1)
    (dotimes (j (1+ i))
      (write-char #\Backspace))))
```

This is how you can print a growing "arrow" on the same line (sending the backspace character as many times as you've printed the equals character will erase it).

Note this will not work in SLIME/SWANK combination because they won't handle "special" characters which could be interpreted as commands, instead they will circumflex-escape them, this one would print as bunches of `^H`, but if you run this in terminal, then it will clean the arrow and re-print it.

---

And this is how you'd do it with `format`ting the string by repeating the same character:

```
(defun progress-bar ()
  (dotimes (i 100)
    (format t (format nil "~~1,1,~d,'=:<>~~>" i))
    (finish-output)
    (sleep 1)
    (dotimes (j (1+ i))
      (write-char #\Backspace))))
```

In case you like more convoluted ways (it is indeed several characters shorter!). And, oh wait, it creates exactly as many strings as the original one... oops :)

---

Unfortunately, I don't know of a good format directive that would plainly repeat a character, so that the above seems to be the simplest way to do it, however, there are other funny ways to do it *efficiently*.

```
(defun progress-bar ()
  (let ((arrow (make-array
                101
                :element-type 'character
                :initial-element #\>
                :fill-pointer 1)))
    (dotimes (i 100)
      (format t arrow)
      (setf (fill-pointer arrow) (+ i 2)
            (aref arrow i) #\=
            (aref arrow (1+ i)) #\>)
      (finish-output)
      (sleep 1)
      (dotimes (j (1+ i))
        (write-char #\Backspace)))))

(defun progress-bar ()
  (let (source)
    (dotimes (i 100)
      (format t "~{~c~}>" source)
      (push #\= source)
      (finish-output)
      (sleep 1)
      (dotimes (j (1+ i))
        (write-char #\Backspace)))))
```

for instance.

Comment: That's not really that good, because you cons up i strings. If you want to be (too?) clever, then you can use a format directive to print i characters.